# create a HTMLCollection

Tags: javascript, dom, dom4

I'm trying to shim [`Element.prototype.children`](http://www.w3.org/TR/domcore/#dom-element-children) which should return a [HTMLCollection](http://www.w3.org/TR/domcore/#htmlcollection)

There is a [`window.HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLCollection)

However

```
var h = new HTMLCollection();
//TypeErrror: HTMLCollection is not a constructor
```

and

```
var h = Object.create(HTMLCollection.prototype);
h[0] = div;
h.item(0); 
// Could not convert JavaScript argument
```

Test Firefox 7 and Chrome

Apart from shimming `HTMLCollection` is there any way to interact with it?

Also provide feedback on [this github issue](https://github.com/Raynos/DOM-shim/issues/5) if you can suggest a solution

Comment: I believe the correct way to do this is to define your own custom `MyHTMLCollection` constructor and then use it instead of the host constructor `HTMLCollection` (which is not reliable)

Comment: While I can't answer your specific question about HTMLCollection, it is generally considered bad practice to extend native DOM (hosted) objects. See this article for a detailed explanation why: http://perfectionkills.com/whats-wrong-with-extending-the-dom/

Comment: @skyline3000 I'm perfectly aware of the consequences. We need to do this to generate a DOM-shim. We're not extending the DOM with custom methods (evil) but with methods that should exist as per the DOM4 specification

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's how I would do it:

```
function MyHTMLCollection( arr ) {
    for ( var i = 0; i < arr.length; i += 1 ) {
        this[i] = arr[i];
    }

    // length is readonly
    Object.defineProperty( this, 'length', {
        get: function () {
            return arr.length;
        }
    });

    // a HTMLCollection is immutable
    Object.freeze( this );
}

MyHTMLCollection.prototype = {
    item: function ( i ) {
        return this[i] != null ? this[i] : null;
    },
    namedItem: function ( name ) {
        for ( var i = 0; i < this.length; i += 1 ) {
            if ( this[i].id === name || this[i].name === name ) {
                return this[i];
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
};
```

where `arr` is a regular array that contains all the DOM elements which should be inside the HTMLCollection.

To do list:

- the argument `arr` should be checked beforehand: Is it an array? Are all elements of that array DOM elements?

Comment: What about `instance[4] = newEl`. `length` would fail. I think you need to calculate length at every get call for it to work.

Comment: @Raynos I just updated my answer. `Object.freeze( this )` inside the constructor, but I'm not sure what the spec says about immutability of HTML collections. I'll check ...

Comment: also `Object.defineProperty` only works on the DOM in IE8 so my dom-shim just broke in IE8. I guess I can make the `length` property a static value in IE8 and just forget about it.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas - [check the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-75708506), collections have a read only length.

Comment: @RobG Yes, I defined it as an accessor property with no setter - this makes it read-only. `{ value: arr.length, writable: false }` would be more proper but this works too.

Comment: For the `item` function, it's probably better to do `return this[i] || null;`. That way you aren't accessing the internal array twice.

Comment: @AlbertoAcuña Which browser?

Answer (score 19):

I think this is the proper way of creating HTMLCollection, which is handled by the browser.

```
var docFragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
docFragment.appendChild(node1);
docFragment.appendChild(node2);
var myHTMLCollection = docFragment.children;
```

Refs.:

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/35969890/10018427
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection
>
> https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_nodelist.asp

Comment: nice! this is newer and more appropriate answer.

Comment: that is a very practical solution

Comment: DocumentFragment must ensure its children detached from previous parent, hence not HTMLCollection counterpart.

Answer (score 6):

Don't expect host objects to behave like (ECMAScript) native objects, they are completely different things. Some browsers do implement their DOM objects like ECMAScript objects, but it is not required and should not be relied upon. Note that most HTML collections are live, it is very difficult to emulate that in a native object.

Comment: They are indeed incredibly difficult to emulate without a Proxy.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an older question but I came across a similar need to create an empty HTMLCollection and I did it by simply creating an element and then running getElementsByClassName() against it using a class that doesn't exist in the element.

```
document.createElement("div").getElementsByClassName('noClassHere');
```

This returns an empty HTMLCollection object.