# HTMLCollection undefined in ie6/7?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

It seems that HTMLCollection and NodeList is undefined in ie6/7,and following code will result an error among ie6/7

```
alert(HTMLCollection)
```

then how to identify weather an object is HTMLCollection?

Comment: Can you give an example why do you need it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HtmlCollection is not available in IE 6/7. You would have to try to shim it as in [create-a-htmlcollection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7754269/create-a-htmlcollection) or use some external library to deal with the problem (which is?)