# jQuery: dynamic selector which stretches after appending new element to selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I want to select elements which include appended new elements also after selecting. I can do it by `document.getElementsByClassName`. It includes new appended elements. Like that:

```
var div1 = $('<div />').addClass('new_div1');
$('body').append(div1)
var divs = document.getElementsByClassName('new_div1')
divs.length // 1
var div2 = $('<div />').addClass('new_div1');
$('body').append(div2)
divs.length // 2; here divs includes newly appended element
```

But I wanted to it with jQuery. I tried like this, but not working as I expected.

```
var div1 = $('<div />').addClass('new_div')
$('body').append(div1)
var divs = $('.new_div')
divs.length // 1
var div2 = $('<div />').addClass('new_div')
$('body').append(div2)
divs.length // 1; here I want to see 2 with newly appended element
```

How can I select elements like `document.getElementsByClassName` in jQuery?

Comment: Why do you want to do this with jQuery, when the underlying JavaScript gives you a live `nodeList` which does this automagically?

Comment: @DavidThomas You're right, but I need to use some jQuery methods on it.

Comment: why can't you run `divs = $('.new_div')` again

Comment: @ArunPJohny It is placed in `for` loop, that's why I didn't want to select each time. I think it's bad practice selecting DOM element in `for` loop.

Comment: jQuery return array like object with chainable feature . `getElementsByClassName` returns `HTMLCollection`.  could u check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7754269/create-a-htmlcollection

Comment: @bob it is valid only if the elements are constant, if they are dynamic there is no other way that running the query again.

Comment: Another solution is possible if the elements are added under your control in that case you can add the dynamically added elements back to the `divs` array using the [add()][http://api.jquery.com/add/] method. ex: `var dynamicels = $('').appendTo(''); divs.add(dynamicels );