# Make a list of all h1, h2

Tags: javascript, html

I use this to make a list of all `<h1>`. **How would you also insert the `<h2>`, as a nested list?**

Should I detect all `<h2>` inside a specific `<h1>`, i.e. use a double loop, or is there a more straightforward approach?

I'm a bit lost about which approach to use.

```js
var toc = document.getElementById('toc'); 
var h1 = document.getElementsByTagName("h1");
for (var i = 0; i < h1.length; i++) {
     var li = document.createElement("li");
     li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(h1[i].textContent));
     toc.appendChild(li);
}
```

```html
Table of contents:

<div>
  <ul id="toc">
  </ul>
</div>  

___

<h1>TitleA</h1>
<h1>TitleB</h1>
<h2>SubTitleB1</h2>
<h2>SubTitleB2</h2>
<h1>TitleC</h1>
<h1>TitleD</h1>
<h2>SubTitleD1</h2>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[You can use `querySelectorAll`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21193495/1848578) to get an ordered list of all `h1` and `h2` elements. Then you can process that list to create a nested table of contents with subheadings:

```js
// parse the ToC content
var list = document.querySelectorAll("h1,h2"); // get all h1 & h2
var tocArr = [], cur; // holds the structure of the ToC
for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
  var e = list[i];
  if (e.tagName == "H1") {
    // for an h1, create a new heading entry (with a blank child list)
    tocArr.push({text:e.textContent, children:(cur=[])});
  } else {
    // for an h2, add it to the current h1's child list
    cur.push(e.textContent);
  }
}
console.log(tocArr);

// build the DOM nodes
var toc = document.getElementById('toc');
for (var i in tocArr) {
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  li.textContent = tocArr[i].text;
  
  // NEW: add a sub-ul for any subheadings
  var ch = tocArr[i].children;
  if (ch.length > 0) {
    var ul = document.createElement("ul");
    for (var i2 in ch) {
      var li2 = document.createElement("li");
      li2.textContent = ch[i2];
      ul.appendChild(li2);
    }
    li.appendChild(ul);
  }
  
  toc.appendChild(li);
}
```

```html
Table of contents:

<div>
  <ul id="toc">
  </ul>
</div>  

___

<h1>TitleA</h1>
<h1>TitleB</h1>
<h2>SubTitleB1</h2>
<h2>SubTitleB2</h2>
<h1>TitleC</h1>
<h1>TitleD</h1>
<h2>SubTitleD1</h2>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Are we sure it's always uppercase when doing `== 'H1'` ?

Comment: From [Element.tagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/tagName#Notes): "On HTML elements in DOM trees flagged as HTML documents, tagName returns the element name in the uppercase form." (You could add `.toUpperCase()` if you felt uncomfortable about it)

Answer (score 1):

You can not combine selectors with `getElementsByTagName()`.

It's possible with `querySelectorAll('h1 h2')`: all `h1` and `h2` elements are returned in a node list you can loop on to create your toc:

```js
var toc = document.getElementById('toc'); 
var h1h2 = document.querySelectorAll("h1, h2");
for (var i = 0; i < h1h2.length; i++) {
  var li = document.createElement("li");
     li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(h1h2[i].textContent));
     toc.appendChild(li);
}
```

```html
Table of contents:

<div>
  <ul id="toc">
  </ul>
</div>  

___

<h1>TitleA</h1>
<h1>TitleB</h1>
<h2>SubTitleB1</h2>
<h2>SubTitleB2</h2>
<h1>TitleC</h1>
<h1>TitleD</h1>
<h2>SubTitleD1</h2>
```

Comment: Thanks, clever solution! How would you do it as a nested list? i.e. SubTitles should be in child `<ul>`. That was the part I was a bit lost with.

Answer (score 1):

Not completely aligned with the detailed demand, but for anyone looking for a quick way to list all headings in a page, here is a simple solution that can be thrown in the console browser to produce a table of content:

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll("h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6")].map(h=>h.textContent).join('\n')
```

```js
console.log([...document.querySelectorAll("h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6")].map(h=>h.textContent).join('\n'))
```

```html
<h1>H1 1</h1>
<h1>H1 2</h1>
<h2>H2 2.1</h2>
<h2>H2 2.2</h2>
<h3>H3 2.2.1</h3>
<h1>H1 3</h1>
```

Comment: It can be useful indeed! Please insert a runnable snippet so that your solution can be tested quickly.

Comment: Here it is @Basj, feel free to request further complements