# Why don't document.getElementsBy__ methods return an HTMLCollection?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, nodelist

Why don't `getElementsByName`, `getElementsByTagName`, and `getElementsByClassName` return an `HTMLCollection` ([W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-author-20110705/common-dom-interfaces.html#htmlcollection-0), [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection)) instead of a `NodeList` ([W3C](http://www.w3.org/2003/01/dom2-javadoc/org/w3c/dom/NodeList.html), [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList))?

All three return a live NodeList of only elements:

```
document.getElementsByName('nameAttrVal');
document.getElementsByTagName('div');
document.getElementsByClassName('space separated classes');
```

NodeLists are great, but `HTMLCollection`s are more specific as they can only contain HTML elements. It seems like this would be perfect for those methods.

> When a collection is created, a filter and a root are associated with
>   the collection.
>
> For example, when the HTMLCollection object for the document.images
>   attribute is created, it is associated with a filter that selects only
>   img elements, and rooted at the root of the document.
>
> The collection then represents a **live** view of the subtree rooted at
>   the collection's root, containing only nodes that match the given
>   filter. The view is linear. In the absence of specific requirements to
>   the contrary, the nodes within the collection must be sorted in tree
>   order.
>
> — [W3C on collections](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-html5-20080610/dom.html#collections)

A couple places `HTMLCollection` is already being used:

```
document.images
element.children
```

**NB:** `querySelectorAll` returns a non-live `NodeList`.

Comment: Well `qSA` was defined a few years after those three APIs, so I think the spec designers agree with you. But you can't go back and change things now.

Comment: Potential duplicate question - [LINK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15763358/difference-between-htmlcollection-nodelists-and-arrays-of-objects)

Comment: @Quinn, I'm not sure that it's a duplicate exactly, but it's certainly relevant.

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/a/7754729/2246362

Comment: Check out [NodeList.js](https://github.com/eorroe/NodeList.js)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTMLCollection was largely only included in the DOM spec to document how most browsers worked before the DOM was introduced. It only makes sense in the context of HTML, whereas the DOM was built to work consistently for both HTML and XML.  Implementations of the DOM are allowed to omit HTMLCollection and all its uses and still be considered conforming; browsers have chosen to keep it to maintain backwards-compatibility with old websites.

Answer (score -2):

Because can exist more tags html elements with same name or class name, and you can manipulate it as DOM object, not as html type

"**Returns the first item with ID or name *name* from the collection**". [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-author-20110705/common-dom-interfaces.html#htmlcollection-0)

If you try catch a event or modify it like as add attributes in a specific node you can do it selected by Id or *name* collection

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean? Could you clarify?