# How to create NodeList object from two or more DOMNodes

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-node

For example I have two DOMNodes:

`let node1 = document.querySelector('#node-1');
let node2 = document.querySelector('#node-2');`

How do I combine them into a NodeList object? Is there an easy solution like `array.push(item)`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add both nodes into a document fragment:

```
var docFragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
docFragment.appendChild(node1);
docFragment.appendChild(node2);
```

And if you really want them in a NodeList do:

```
var list = docFragment.querySelectorAll('*');
```

The down side to this is that as soon as you append the nodes to the document fragment you remove them from the actual document.

Comment: Is there a difference between document fragment and node list? In the API.

Comment: a document fragment technically holds an HTMLCollection, but for most practical uses it's the same as a NodeList.

Answer (score 2):

Consider this as an addition to Orr Siloni's answer:

If we don't want the node to be removed from the DOM, we can append a copy of the node using `node.cloneNode()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
var nList = document.querySelectorAll('[id^="node"]');
```

Collect all nodes with an id that starts with "node".

```js
var nList = document.querySelectorAll('[id^="node"]');
for (var i = 0; i < nList.length; i++) {
  var node = nList[i].id;
  console.log('Node: ' + node);
}
```

```html
<div id="node-1">node-1</div>
<div id="node-2">node-2</div>
<div id="notnode-3">notnode-3</div>
<div id="check">Check the console (F12, then choose the 'console' tab)</div>
```