# How to initialize special Objects namely interfaces in javascript?

Tags: javascript, object, interface, initialization

When I initialize some Classes/Interfaces like `Node`, `NodeList`, `HTMLCollection` etc, I get an error: `Illegal Constructor`

For eg:

> `var x = new Node();`

***Uncaught TypeError: Illegal constructor

    at <anonymous>:1:9***

> `var x = new HTMLCollection()`;

***Uncaught TypeError: Illegal constructor

    at <anonymous>:1:9***

Question1: **Why this error happens ?**

Question2: **How to initialize such objects?**

Question3: **Why those Objects are named as *Interfaces*? Although no such keywords exists in JavaScript**

Question4: **What else should I know about these kind of Objects/Classes?**

I hope, I provided much description to answerers and I also hope to get my answer soon.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [create a HTMLCollection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7754269/create-a-htmlcollection)

Comment: Interfaces are like abstract classes in other OO languages. You can't instantiate them by themselves, you can only instantiate subclasses.